# C# dataGridView doesnt show information I want it to show

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have two dataGridView tables. One with Suppliers, second with Products. I want them to work like that: When I click on the row in Suppliers dataGridView, in Products dataGridView it would show only products from selected supplier.
This is function I wrote for that purpose:

```
static public void SuppliersProducts(DataGridView _productslist)
   {
       try
       {
           connection.Open();
           SqlCommand commandShow = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.Name FROM Products a INNER JOIN SuppliersProducts b ON a.Id = b.ProductId WHERE b.SupplierId = @SupplierId", connection);
           DataGridViewRow dr1 = _productslist.SelectedRows[0];
           commandShow.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierId", dr1.Cells[0].Value);
           commandShow.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (SqlException exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close();
       }
   }
```

Im using it in dataGridView1_CellMouseClick:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        SuppliersProducts(ProductsList);
    }
```

Where ProductsList is my dataGridView for Products table. The problem is that it doesnt throw any errors but when I click on certain supplier in my first dataGridView table nothing happens with the second one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

change the `CellMouseClick` event with `CellClick` because `CellMouseClick` fires when any mouse button clicks on cell

and the data of sql server should store somewhere

and ExecuteNonQuery() use for Insert,Delete, Update and the commands that does not return data

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        SuppliersProducts(ProductsList,e.RowIndex);
    }


static public void SuppliersProducts(DataGridView _productslist,int index)
   {
       try
       {
           connection.Open();

           string commandShow=String.Format("SELECT a.Name FROM Products a INNER JOIN SuppliersProducts b ON a.Id = b.ProductId WHERE b.SupplierId = {0}",_productslist.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value));
           //Stroing sql server data
          var dt = new DataTable();
          using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(commandShow, connection))
              da.Fill(dt);
           foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row[0],...);
           }
       }
       catch (SqlException exception)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: it says, that it cant run foreach for dt, because DataTable does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'